# WooCommerce products in Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type

I am trying to use the Woocommerce category taxonomy to display relevant products on a page. The custom post type allows me to add the product category list to the custom page but I am not sure how to filter it to only show the category I select for the respective page. At the moment it is showing all my products, not filtering the ones I need:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat' );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    global $product; 
    echo '<div class="background-img"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().'<br /> '.get_the_title().'</a>';
    echo $product->get_price_html();
    echo '<form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="';
    echo esc_attr($product->id);
    echo '">
     <button type="submit">';
    echo $product->single_add_to_cart_text();
    echo '</button>
        </form>';
    echo '</div>';
endwhile; 

$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id )
{
    echo $image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );

}
wp_reset_query();
```

Here is a version of the dev site, it is still quite raw and needs alot of styling but should give an idea:

http://betamarine.mainboard.com/engine/beta-14-z482/

I'm using the following plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

I can create a custom taxonomy but it is an extra step and produces the same results. I think I may be missing something small but I'm just not getting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after much struggle here is the code snippet:

```html
 <?php

   //retrieves the term variable from the admin page - replace "product_category" with the name of your post type
$part_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_category' );
if( $part_terms && !is_wp_error( $part_terms ) ) {
    foreach( $part_terms as $term ) {
    }
}
//create a variable to filter your Wordpress Loop
    $part_args = array( 
  'post_type' => 'product', 
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'posts_per_page' => -1, 
  'tax_query' => array(array(
   'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
   'field' => 'slug',
   'terms' => array($term->slug),
   'operator' => 'IN'
   ))
 );

       
    $loop = new WP_Query( $part_args );
//the loop
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    global $product; 
//some handy woocommerce coding
 echo '<div class="background-img"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().'<br /> '.get_the_title().'</a>';
 echo $product->get_price_html();
 echo '<form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="';
 echo esc_attr($product->id); 
 echo '">
     <button type="submit">';
 echo $product->single_add_to_cart_text(); 
 echo '</button>
  </form>';
 echo '</div>';
      endwhile;

?>
```

Thanks JayDeep for setting me on the right track!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use tax_query for use filter by texonomy.

Check this link:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: Thanks for the response, read through the codex and came up with this:

 `$args = array( 
 'post_type' => 'product', 
 'posts_per_page' => -1, 
 'tax-query' => array(array(
   'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
   'field' => 'slug',
   'terms' => array($cat->slug),
   'operator' => 'IN'
   ))
  );`

it is not doing anything though, still just showing all the products, not very good at PHP - am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, you are in right track you can change : 'tax-query' => array(array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => array($cat->slug), 'operator' => 'IN' )) array to as per your requirement. for e.g. operator support "IN", "=", "LIKE", ">", "<" etc.

Comment: Oh my word, just realised I was using  'tax-query' instead of 'tax_query' - with an underscore!
That said, if I add the term name (eg. 'engine')in the place of array($category->slug) it works, if I add the variable call nothing shows. I suspect it may be calling something else on the page?